# Flutter SVG image not able load

Tags: css, flutter, dart, svg

I am trying to load svg image with `flutter_svg`, But In my case some image not able to load even can't find error log for why not displaying image. facing issue in many image below is one of them

j.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 53 61">
  <text id="J" font-size="52" font-weight="700"><tspan x="10.882" y="48">J</tspan></text>
</svg>
```

Can any one help me out this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg package for Svg image.

eg:-

```
final Widget networkSvg = SvgPicture.network(
  'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
  semanticsLabel: 'A shark?!',
  placeholderBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
);
```

Comment: Using same package, But not loading some images like mention in question